# Composition of services is it possible with kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I have a pod in which i have image ubuntu desktop i connect to this image via xrdp what i want to do is to add eclipse image to this pod in other words when i connect to this ubuntu desktop i can find eclipse.

I am going to create platform based on kubernetes with image catalog.
For example a profesor of java want only ubuntu desktop and eclipse. He gonna choose from catalog ubuntu and eclipse all backend i will do it myself.
So when a student connect he will find eclipse on ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider to read the [How to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this question doesn't show what you did and tried already and is far to broad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an image from a dockerfile recipe that includes a command for installing the eclipse package.

Then you can use your own image for the deployment into the cluster (instead of the ubuntu image you are using today).

Please read up [how to create a docker container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/) and [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) documentation.

You can also take a look at an [example dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/albertalvarezbruned/ubuntu-eclipse/~/dockerfile/).

Comment: So it is impossible with kubernetes? Only with Docker?

Comment: Kubernetes is only hosting docker containers. You use Docker to create the containers and you use kubernetes for hosting them in a clusterized fashion. Hence if you need a container with different content the recommendation is to create it with Docker, as you then have a reproducible recipe that can be reused to recreate the containers and the resulting container can be arbitrarily often deployed identically. I'd recommend to read up on the basics in terms of what the purpose of kubernetes is. For example this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-kubernetes

Comment: And to answer your question - The only way you can use kubernetes for your use case is to run a command inside the pod for installing the eclipse package (but then it will only be in the specific pod you run the command in and when the pod is terminated your eclipse installation is gone - thus not recommended). To run commands use `kubectl exec <pod-name> <command>`